# UITextView does not respect the secureTextEntry property

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to get a UITextView (**NOT** a UITextField) to act as a password field where the text is obfuscated as you type into it.  However, setting this property to YES on a UITextView seems to have no effect and the letters are always visible instead of only being visible if it's the last letter typed and a dot otherwise.  Has anyone else run into this and know why this happens or what a possible workaround may be?  If necessary I can use a UITextField in the instances that I specifically need password behavior but that would not be as clean as just using UITextView only.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the UITextView for password? Do you need the scroll?

Comment: It would make my code a lot cleaner since my UI is not static; it is configurable based on a number of factors and it would be a lot easier to just have everything use one kind of control if possible.

Comment: I also met,You can refer to this： "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440781/uitextview-securetextentry-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1"

Comment: I also met,You can refer to this："https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440781/uitextview-securetextentry-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that specific UITextInputTraits simply does not work on the UITextView. It is intended for password fields (`UITextField`).