# UITextVIew secureTextEntry not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

Possible Duplicates [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164809/uitextview-does-not-respect-the-securetextentry-property) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382786/securetextentry-doesnt-hide-the-text-of-my-uitextview) (But they don't have solution for my problem)

I am creating a chat UI where my textbox MUST have both **Multiple Line** feature and **Secure Text Entry** Feature.

UITextField doesn't have Multiple Line Feature

UITextView doesn't have Secure Text Entry Feature

What should i do now ?

> **Another doubt, if secureTextEntry for UITextView not going to work, why the heck they put that property inside UITextView Class**

Comment: I am creating a Chat App. I want it should have multiple line option (Like in whatsapp). I may also need secured text entry option in some cases.

Comment: then use `UITextView` and whenever user starts Secure text then show `*` on UI instead of original character and in backend save your each and every character properly, thats the only approach i think is possible.

Comment: Use `UITextView` by default for normal text. If the user wants to enter some secure text, there must be something like a checkbox saying that he wants to enter secure text. If he selects that, replace your `UITextView` with `UITextField`.

Comment: @PrerakSola you can not replace components like this, for more details try with demo and feel the `user interface`

Answer (score 2):

> Only UITextField supports secureTextEntry, making a font that consists entirely of asterisks and use it in text view once you select secure option. Also be sure to disable copying.

[View this link for better understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164809/uitextview-does-not-respect-the-securetextentry-property?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: you can not replace components like this

Comment: @Ganesh would it rejected by apple ?can you please update me thanks

Comment: Good idea but I don't know how to make a font. Is there a link where I can download such a font?

Comment: i think you need to create new font ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use hack for it. You can use predefined `delegate` method of `UITextView` and which is `textViewDidChange`
So maintain one flag which will keep state of whether you want secured entry or not.
e.g.,

```
NSString *originalText = @"";
BOOL isSecuredEntryOn = false;
```

Change it to `true` whenever you want to add secured text like `BOOL isSecuredEntryOn = true;`

Now this will be code of your `delegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    originalText = [originalText stringByAppendingString:text];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSString *enteredText = textView.text;
    textView.text = (isSecuredEntryOn) ? [enteredText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:enteredText withString:[self getSecuredTextFor:enteredText]] : enteredText;
}

-(NSString *)getSecuredTextFor:(NSString *)stringToConvert {
    NSString *securedString = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i < stringToConvert.length; i++) {
        securedString = [securedString stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
    }
    return securedString;
}
```

You can use anything instead of * for secured text.

Comment: But where can i get the Original Text entered ? When textViewChange called second time, my original text will be replaced by star. Hence i can get only astriks

Comment: I edited answer. You can take one variable which will hold original entered text for you and use it for further operations.

Comment: Say if i am going to type '1234'. When i type '1',originalText will hold '1'. When i type '2', then originalText will have ' *2 ' . So i can't retain my original text if i take it from textView.text each time.

Comment: No No, When you type 1, original text will be @"1" as textView.text = @"1". Now if you type 2, original text will become @"12" as textView.text = @"12"

Comment: No, when you type second character, first character would have changed to astrik. So, if you get from textView.text, it will return astrik only

Comment: I tested your code also, it returns astrik symbol only

Comment: Try now, I added shouldChangeTextInRange as well. Now shouldChangeTextInRange will get calls when you enter something and then textViewDidChange will gets called. So originalText will hold proper text. Fingers crossed.

Comment: What is this `[originalText stringByAppendingString:@"text"]` , I mean how it will work ? Why are you appending "text" ? It doesn't work.

Comment: Check now. It should be [originalText stringByAppendingString:text] instead of [originalText stringByAppendingString:@"text"]. My Bad.

Comment: What about when you delete some characters?

Comment: I think it should be `originalText = [originalText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text]` instead of `originalText = [originalText stringByAppendingString:text]`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by subclassing `UITextView` and adding to it some properties similar to the ones Pushkraj added. It perfectly works in many scenarios (... at least at the time writing this post).

My whole answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350447/set-password-protection-in-uitextview/52958784#52958784).