# Set password protection in UITextView

Tags: swift, textview, passwords

Can i hide password in UITextView by * or any other symbol? I need to use UITextView instead of UITextField. I want to hide all characters of textView.

Comment: you want to hide all characters or specific characters of textview ?

Comment: All Characters @TaimoorSuleman

Comment: `isSecureTextEntry = true`

Comment: He needs this to work on an `UITextView` not an `UITextField`

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman I have already tried it. But it is not reflecting.

Comment: wait, let me write a code for you

Comment: Why do you need a textview if a password is a single line input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `UITextView` leaves the whole job of masking the text yourself. You also need to make sure you disable copying for security reasons. Set your `delegate` property and handle this something on these lines:

```
var originalText: String?

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    originalText = ((originalText ?? "") as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    return true
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.text = String(repeating: "*", count: (textView.text ?? "").count)
}
```

If you need to retrieve the value of the actual text that was input use the `originalText` property.

Comment: Thanks. It's Working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable for password string.

```
var passwordString = ""
```

Then set delegates of UITextView like:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    passwordString = ((passwordString ?? "") as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    return true
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
//replace character with * or anyother character
    yourtextView.text = String(repeating: "*", count: (textView.text ?? "").count)
}
```

and dont forget to do this:

```
yourTextview.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to share my own implementation after using the previous answers for a while in a chat-like app, where the `UITextView` is constantly filled and emptied.

My `UITextView` works as an entry of text for different kind of data types (phones, e-mails, etc.) and I did not want to create other `UITextView` specifically for handling this scenario, so I decided to subclass it and restructure a little bit the code because I faced with circumstances that the logic breaks when using an external keyboard or changing the `text` property programatically (doing the last one [does not call the delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate)).

So first subclassing...

### `UITextView` subclass

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {

    var isProtected = false // `true` for activate the password mode
    var plainText: String! = String() // Variable to save the text when `isProtected`

    override var text: String! {
        get { return isProtected ? plainText : super.text }
        set {
            if !isProtected {
                plainText = newValue
            }
            super.text = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

---

*PS: The overriding of the `text` property helps us to get always the plain text in the `UITextView` without calling other variables.*

---

Then, in the view controller where the delegate is implemented...

### `UITextViewDelegate`

```
extension MyViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if myTextView.isProtected {
            myTextView.plainText = (myTextView.plainText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text) // Basically: when is in password mode, saves all written characters in our auxiliar variable
        }

        return true
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if myTextView.isProtected {
            textView.text = String(repeating: "•", count: textView.text.count) // Change every letter written with the character "•"
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, you only need to toggle the `isProtected` flag somewhere in `MyViewController` and that`s it:

```
myTextView.isProtected = true //or `false`
```