# How can I Implement Hide/Show password style experience for iOS with UITextView in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I understand that the password-style effect can be implemented for `UITextFields` using the `SecureTextEntry` property, and I also found some code online to implement Hide/Show password effect [here](https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-tip-implement-show-hide-password-usin), but this only works for `UITextFields`, I need to implement this same feature for a Custom `UITextView`. I currently have some code to implement add the image for the UI, but the actual Show/Hide password effect is not implemented.

I found some code for how to do this in `Swift` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350447/set-password-protection-in-uitextview), but I have never worked with `Swift` and was hoping that someone who is familiar with `Swift` can translate this to `C#` for me, as this could possibly be the solution I need.

I also understand that while the `SecureTextEntry` property gives the password-style experience for `UITextFields` when set to true ***(ie prevents copying and turns characters into black dots)***, it only prevents copying of text when set to true for `UITextViews`. This I found from the documentation of this property [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624427-securetextentry)

Here is the code which I currently have in my file that implements the **Show/Hide password effect**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Xamarin")]
[assembly:ExportEffect(typeof(MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.PasswordEffect), "PasswordEffect")]
namespace MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class PasswordEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            Configure();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        private void Configure()
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (Control is UITextView) {
                    UITextView vUpdatedEntry = (UITextView)Control;
                    var buttonRect = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
                    buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("eye_image"), UIControlState.Normal);
                    buttonRect.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e1) => {
                        if (vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry)
                        {
                            vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry = false;
                            buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("eye_crossed_image"), UIControlState.Normal);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry = true;
                            buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("eye_image"), UIControlState.Normal);
                        }
                    };
                    // Would love to have password effect here :)
                    vUpdatedEntry.ShouldChangeText += (textField, range, replacementString) => {
                        string text = vUpdatedEntry.Text;
                        var result = text.Substring(0, (int)range.Location) + replacementString + text.Substring((int)range.Location + (int)range.Length);
                        vUpdatedEntry.Text = result;
                        return false;
                    };

                    buttonRect.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f, 15.0f);
                    buttonRect.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

                    UIView paddingViewRight = new UIView(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 18.0f));
                    paddingViewRight.AddSubview(buttonRect);

                    buttonRect.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
                    buttonRect.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(paddingViewRight.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

                    vUpdatedEntry.TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(8.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, paddingViewRight.Frame.Width+5.0f);
                    vUpdatedEntry.AddSubview(paddingViewRight);

                    paddingViewRight.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
                    paddingViewRight.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.TrailingAnchor, 9.0f).Active = true;
                    paddingViewRight.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.HeightAnchor).Active = true;
                    paddingViewRight.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(buttonRect.WidthAnchor,1.0f, 0.0f).Active = true;

                    Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
                    Control.Layer.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor(255, 255, 255);
                    Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
                    vUpdatedEntry.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle I was finally able to get this done. Much thanks to @JuniorJiang-MSFT who led me in the right direction. My code for my the file that implements the effect is shown below:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Foundation;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Xamarin")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.ShowHidePasswordEffect), "ShowHidePasswordEffect")]
namespace MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class ShowHidePasswordEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        //The actual text entered by the user.
        private NSMutableString SecureText;
        private NSTimer timer;
        //The last character(s) entered by the user.
        private NSString LastText;
        private UITextView UiTextViewForControl;
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            SecureText = new NSMutableString();
            ConfigureControl();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            //do nothing
        }


        private void ConfigureControl()
        {
            if (Control != null)
            { 
                if (Control is UITextView) {
                    UITextView vUpdatedEntry = (UITextView)Control;
                    this.UiTextViewForControl = vUpdatedEntry;

                    var buttonRect = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
                    buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("show_black_24"), UIControlState.Normal);
                    buttonRect.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e1) => {
                        if (vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry)
                        {
                            vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry = false;
                            buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("hide_black_24"), UIControlState.Normal);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vUpdatedEntry.SecureTextEntry = true;
                            buttonRect.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("show_black_24"), UIControlState.Normal);
                        }
                        // Change the text based on whether password is to be hidden or visible.
                        HandleSecureEntryChange(vUpdatedEntry);
                    };

                    vUpdatedEntry.ShouldChangeText += (textView, range, toReplaceText) => {
                        if ("\n" == toReplaceText)
                        {   //Drop the keyboard if 'Enter/Return' is pressed
                            vUpdatedEntry.ResignFirstResponder();
                            return false;
                        }
                        //Get the text that was entered, store that in LastText. Return true, so that Changed is called.
                        LastText = new NSString(toReplaceText);
                        return true;
                    };
                    // Add eventHandler for Changed.
                    vUpdatedEntry.Changed += HandleTextChange;

                    buttonRect.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

                    UIView paddingViewRight = new UIView(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 18.0f));
                    paddingViewRight.AddSubview(buttonRect);

                    buttonRect.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
                    buttonRect.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(paddingViewRight.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

                    vUpdatedEntry.AddSubview(paddingViewRight);

                    paddingViewRight.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
                    paddingViewRight.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.TrailingAnchor, 8.0f).Active = true;
                    paddingViewRight.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.HeightAnchor).Active = true;
                    paddingViewRight.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
                    paddingViewRight.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(vUpdatedEntry.LayoutMarginsGuide.TopAnchor, -8.0f).Active = true;
                    paddingViewRight.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(buttonRect.WidthAnchor, 1.0f, 3.0f).Active = true;
                    vUpdatedEntry.TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(8.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, paddingViewRight.Frame.Width + 5.0f);

                    Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
                    Control.Layer.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor(255, 255, 255);
                    Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
                    vUpdatedEntry.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
                }
            }
        }

        private void HandleTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UITextView customEditor = (UITextView)sender;
            if (customEditor.SecureTextEntry)
            {
                string text = customEditor.Text;
                if (text.Length > 0)
                {
                    //If LastText is empty, that means deletion occured.
                    if ("" == this.LastText)
                    {   //Delete the last character from the actual text
                        this.SecureText.DeleteCharacters(new NSRange(this.SecureText.Length - 1, 1));
                        if (null != timer)
                        {
                            timer.Invalidate();
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    // If LastText is not empty, that means (a) new character(s) was/were entered.
                    int lastTextLength = ((this.LastText.ToString()).Length); //Number of characters in LastText.
                    if (lastTextLength > 1)
                    {   // If more than one character was entered (usually by pasting)
                        int NewTextStartIndex = (text.Length - lastTextLength);
                        string TempNewCharacters = text.Substring(NewTextStartIndex);
                        // Get all the characters except the last character and add them to the secureText
                        NSString NewCharacters = new NSString(TempNewCharacters.Substring(0, TempNewCharacters.Length - 1));
                        SecureText.Append(NewCharacters);

                    }
                    // Get and add the last character
                    NSString LastCharacter = new NSString(text.Substring(text.Length - 1));
                    this.SecureText.Append(LastCharacter);
                    // Change all characters to '●' except the last character
                    NSMutableString temp = new NSMutableString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.SecureText.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        temp.Append(new NSString("●"));

                    }
                    // Add the last character as a plain text to the temp and set that into the editor.
                    temp.Append(new NSString(this.SecureText.ToString().Substring(this.SecureText.ToString().Length - 1)));
                    customEditor.Text = temp;

                    if (null != this.timer)
                    {
                        this.timer.Invalidate();
                    }
                    // Wait two seconds before changing the last character to '●'.
                    this.timer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(2, ChangeToHidden);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SecureText = new NSMutableString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If the password is plain text, then initialize it to the secureText string.
                SecureText = new NSMutableString();
                SecureText.SetString(new NSString(customEditor.Text));
                if (null != timer)
                {
                    this.timer.Invalidate();
                }
            }
            CustomEditor ActualCustomEditor = (CustomEditor)Element;
            ActualCustomEditor.PlainText = SecureText.ToString();
        }

        private void ChangeToHidden(object sender)
        {
            // Change all the text entered to '●'
            UITextView customEditor = this.UiTextViewForControl;
            this.timer.Invalidate();
            NSMutableString temp = MakeHiddenText();
            customEditor.Text = temp;
        }

        private void HandleSecureEntryChange(object sender)
        {
            if (this.SecureText.Length > 0)
            {   // If SecureTextEntry is true, hide text, else make plain text and clean the timer.
                UITextView customEditor = (UITextView)sender;
                if (customEditor.SecureTextEntry)
                {
                    NSMutableString temp = MakeHiddenText();
                    customEditor.Text = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    customEditor.Text = this.SecureText;
                    if (null != timer)
                    {
                        this.timer.Invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private NSMutableString MakeHiddenText()
        //Make string of '●''s for the text and return
        {
            NSMutableString temp = new NSMutableString();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.SecureText.Length; i++)
            {
                temp.Append(new NSString("●"));
            }
            return temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Code for my **CustomRenderer** is shown below:

```
using MyApp.CustomControls;
using MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer: EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null && Element != null) {
                var element = (CustomEditor)this.Element;
                if (element.IsPassword) {
                    UITextView uiTextView = (UITextView)Control;
                    uiTextView.SecureTextEntry = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the file which subclasses the `Editor`, I have added a property `PlainText` which will be used to get the actual text when it is hidden. In my **XAML** I bind this property to the variable that should hold the text entered into the control. Below is the relevant code from my `CustomEditor`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.CustomControls
{
    public class CustomEditor : Editor
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty PlainTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlainText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CustomEditor),
                String.Empty,
                defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged:OnPlainTextChanged);

        public string PlainText {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlainTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlainTextProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnPlainTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (CustomEditor)bindable;
            if (newValue != null)
            {
                control.PlainText = newValue.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It is necessary to specify the `defaultBindingMode` as `TwoWay` and also specify a method for `propertyChanged` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom `UITextViewDelegate` to realize it .

```
public class TextViewDelegate : UITextViewDelegate
{
    private UITextView myTextView;
    bool secureTextViewEntry;       // default is NO
    NSMutableString secureText;
    NSTimer timer;
    NSString lastText;
    public TextViewDelegate(UITextView myTextView)
    {
        this.myTextView = myTextView; 
        secureTextViewEntry = false;
        secureText = new NSMutableString();
    }

    public override bool ShouldChangeText(UITextView textView, NSRange range, string text)
    {
        if("\n" == text)
        {
            textView.ResignFirstResponder();
            return false;
        }
        lastText = new NSString(text);
        return true;
        //return base.ShouldChangeText(textView, range, text);
    }

    public override void Changed(UITextView textView)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----" + secureText);
        if (secureTextViewEntry)
        {
            string text = textView.Text;
            if(text.Length > 0)
            {
                if("" == lastText)
                {
                    secureText.DeleteCharacters(new NSRange(secureText.Length - 1, 1));
                    onlyPassword();
                    if (null != timer)
                    {
                        timer.Invalidate();
                    }
                    //base.Changed(textView);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    NSString one = new NSString(text.Substring(text.Length - 1));
                    secureText.Append(one);
                    NSMutableString temp = new NSMutableString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < secureText.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        temp.Append(new NSString("•"));
                    }
                    temp.Append(new NSString(secureText.ToString().Substring(secureText.ToString().Length - 1)));
                    myTextView.Text = temp;

                    if (null != timer)
                    {
                        timer.Invalidate();
                    }
                    timer =NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(2, onlyPassword);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                secureText = new NSMutableString();

            }
            //base.Changed(textView);
        }
        else {
            if (textView.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                secureText = new NSMutableString();
            }
            else
            {
                secureText = new NSMutableString();
                secureText.SetString(new NSString(textView.Text));
            }
            if(null != timer) {
                timer.Invalidate();
            }

            //base.Changed(textView);
        }
    }


    private void onlyPassword(NSTimer obj)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        onlyPassword();
    }

    private void onlyPassword()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        timer.Invalidate();
        NSMutableString temp = new NSMutableString();
        for(int i = 0; i< secureText.Length; i++)
        {
            temp.Append(new NSString("•"));
        }
        myTextView.Text = temp;
    }

    public override void DidChange(NSKeyValueChange changeKind, NSIndexSet indexes, NSString forKey)
    {
        base.DidChange(changeKind, indexes, forKey);
    }
    //set Secure be true or false
    public void setSecureTextViewEntry(bool _secureTextViewEntry)
    {
        secureTextViewEntry = _secureTextViewEntry;
        if (secureText.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (secureTextViewEntry)
            {
                //secret
                NSMutableString aaa = new NSMutableString();
                for (int i = 0; i < secureText.Length; i++)
                {
                    aaa.Append(new NSString("•"));
                }
                myTextView.Text = aaa;
            }else{
                //real word
                myTextView.Text = secureText;
                if (null != timer)
                {
                    timer.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
        Changed(myTextView);
    }

    public bool getSecureTextViewEntry()
    {
        return secureTextViewEntry;
    }
}
```

In ViewController :

```
TextViewDelegate textViewDelegate;

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
     base.ViewDidLoad ();

     textViewDelegate = new TextViewDelegate(MyTextView);
     MyTextView.Delegate = textViewDelegate; //MyTextView from StoryBoard

}

partial void SetTrueButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    textViewDelegate.setSecureTextViewEntry(true);
}

partial void SetFalseButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    textViewDelegate.setSecureTextViewEntry(false);
}
```

Here is the effect :

[image]

**Note**:Code is only for reference, and there are some minor issues in the code that need to be improved.

Comment: Thank for your answer. The output looks very similar to my desired outcome. However, I'm having trouble applying this solution to my situation. I am already using a custom `UITextView`, and I have a class to implement this functionality as an effect, (I am using the `Control` to define this effect for my custom `UITextView`) and I was hoping you could explain how your code works further (maybe with some comments in your answer). As I don't understand fully how custom delegates work and I'm hoping I won't have to use one :)

Comment: @Kikanye Okey , first I want to know which project is ( Forms or Xamarin.IOS) . Second using delegate not need to modify your too much code .You just need to create a `TextViewDelegate` file in Xamarin.ios, then assign this delegate to your used TextFiled , if Forms will use Custom Renderer to set it , such as : `Control.Delegate = new TextViewDelegate(Control);` , else if Xamarin.IOS use as the answer said.If not clearly , you can show code about custom textfiled.

Comment: @Kikanye And here is [Cusotm Renderer document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) for reference if needed.

Comment: It is a `Xamarin.Forms` project, but this is only for the `Xamarin.IOS` part of the project, as this was pretty easy to do for the `Xamarin.Android` version. My main reason for seeking an explanation (in form of comments) is more so that I understand the code and am able to make changes to it if need be, as opposed to just copying and pasting. If you could explain the function of a `Delegate` in this case which you have used it,  and add some comments to the algorithm, that would be awesome, I will test run the code and if it works I can mark this answer correct. :)

Comment: I am using an effect to implement this, and I was hoping I could use your code as reference to implement this as an effect. I have added the code for my effect to the question. Also if you think using a Delegate would still be the best way to go, could you explain how that would work with using an effect? Thanks, looking forward to your answer :)

Comment: @Kikanye Okey , I will check it . If have  a result will share here.

Answer (score -1):

There are two parts to your question.

1. You can probably prevent copying and pasting stuff by subclassing the UITextView, as shown:

```
public class ProtectedTextView : UITextView
{
    public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender)
    {
        if (action == new Selector("paste:") || (action == new Selector("copy:")))
            return false;
        else
            return base.CanPerform(action, withSender);
    }
}
```

2. For show/hide, the equivalent of what you are looking at is:

```
textView.ShouldChangeText = (textField, range, replacementString) =>
{
     string text = textView.Text;
     var result = text.Substring(0, (int) range.Location) + replacementString + text.Substring((int) range.Location + (int) range.Length);
     textView.Text = result;
     return false;
};
```

I haven't tested the code to work though, so let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. For preventing copying from the `UITextView`, I was stating that setting the `SecureTextEntry` property to `true` handles that, so I wont be needing to implement that. I also tried using the code you provided for part **2** of your answer but it does not work, any tweaks or ideas?